# How to create linear layout with different orientation within textviews programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create linear layout with different orientation within `textviews` programatically?

I want to create linear layouts

The first  `linearlayout` with horizontal orientation as parent, then inside first parent layout I want to create 7 `linearlayouts` and  textviews and the 7 created `textviews` should be below the 7 `linearlayots`....

**Expected result:**

[image: see image to ans more clearly]

Comment: and why exactly you want to do this programatically?

Comment: probably because of an unpredictable number of letters...

Comment: Why not just use a RecyclerView & RecyclerAdapter?

Comment: One could also customize a ListView to achieve more or less the same result. But there doesn't seem to be any need for recycling here... It's not a large amount of data, only a name :)

Answer (score -1):

The notion of layouts "within" TextViews doesn't exist, it can't be done. We put TextViews in layouts instead.

I'd suggest one big horizontal LinearLayout, in which you add the number of vertical LinearLayout that you need. Each of these vertical layouts containing two textViews, one for the big letter and one for the small word.

You should define part of it in the XML though. The inner layout (the vertical one) could be in an XML file with it's two TextViews. Then for each letter you load the XML using the `LayoutInflater` and just set the two textView's values.

Comment: If I may, dynamically creating layouts with the LayoutInflater is quite programmatic. Is there a specific reason why there must be ABSOLUTELY NO xml file in your code?